# Pandas drop duplicates ignoring NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

In a Pandas df, I am trying to drop duplicates across multiple columns. Lots of data per row is `NaN`.

This is only an example, the data is a mixed bag, so many different combinations exist.

```
df.drop_duplicates()

    IDnum       name            formNumber
1   NaN         AP GROUP        028-11964
2   1364615.0   AP GROUP        NaN
3   NaN         AP GROUP        NaN
```

Hopeful Output:

```
    IDnum       name            formNumber
1   1364615.0   AP GROUP        028-11964
```

EDIT:

If the `df.drop_duplicates()` looks like this, would it change the solution? :

```
df.drop_duplicates()

    IDnum       name            formNumber
0   NaN         AP GROUP        028-11964
1   1364615.0   AP GROUP        028-11964
2   1364615.0   AP GROUP        NaN
3   NaN         AP GROUP        NaN
```

Comment: I'd guess this is a symptom of `float('nan') != float('nan')` (or whatever the Pandas equivalent is for non-float NaNs) being truthy, since NaN values are not equal to anything, including themselves.

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
df.bfill().ffill().drop_duplicates()
```

Output:

```
IDnum   name    formNumber
0   1364615.0   AP GROUP    028-11964
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't example correctly that the df was many different "id's", But this method at first look was correct. But in fact created a bunch of incorrect results. It seemed to create mismatching indiscriminately.

Comment: Doing this with groupby is likely what most readers are after - or at least, I was.

Answer (score 3):

You can using `groupby` + `first`

```
df.groupby('name',as_index=False).first()
Out[206]: 
      name      IDnum formNumber
0  APGROUP  1364615.0  028-11964
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways we can remove duplicates from a dataframe. few common ways are:

```
#option 1
df.drop_duplicates()

#option 2
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()
```

The major difference between this two options are :

1. option 1 considers NAN values. for example in your case

   ```
    df.drop_duplicates()

        IDnum       name            formNumber
    0   NaN         AP GROUP        028-11964
    1   1364615.0   AP GROUP        028-11964
    2   1364615.0   AP GROUP        NaN
    3   NaN         AP GROUP        NaN
   ```

Here index 0,1,2,3 all are unique rows although duplicates exist in some form.

2. option 2 considers only non NAN values and filters the duplicates as explained in first answer by @BENY

df.groupby('name',as_index=False).first()

```
      name    IDnum formNumber
0  APGROUP  1364615.0  028-11964
```

here in the above case we see only one unique and non duplicated value as group by did not consider NAN's.

To better understand this we can do:

```
df.drop_duplicates().info()
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).first().info()
```

by running the above code we get different count for "non-null" records. this explains how many nulls ignored in 2nd option as compared to 1st option.