# How do I merge multiple rows in Dataframe when some column values are empty?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this: changed labels for posting: You can see that. SSN, Student ID and Driving License will be unique.  How do I do that in Python (PD/NP)

```
Name    SSN     Student_ID   DrivingLicenseNumber

Smith   None    1234         DL1234
Smith   None    None         DL1234
Smith   2222    1234         None     
None    2222    None         None
```

You can notice, For Simith, not all values are present in each row. I am trying to get to **one** row for smith like below. Any pointers will be much appreciated. I know I can load to MySQL and do this but can't figureout best way in DF.

```
None    SSN    Student_ID    DrivingLicenseNumber
Smith   2222   1234          DL1234
```

Comment: Possible dupe, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51217888/4985099

Comment: @Sushanth `groupby.first` doesn't work with `None`.

Comment: Combine `groupby.first` with [`fillna`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743460/replace-none-with-nan-in-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: @sadeepkadapa Yes was about  to edit, before that replace `None` to `NaN` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52488608/4985099

Comment: I can change None to NaN or empty string anyting using df = df.replace( {np.nan: None} ) type function.

Comment: I don't think a single `first` is sufficient. The point is that the unique keys can be missing.

Comment: @RaviP Can you provide another example with different values?

Answer (score 1):

Search and shift the maximum index not null and drop any column that has null.

```
 df.apply(lambda x:x.shift(-(x.notna().idxmax()))).dropna(thresh=4)
  
  Name    SSN    Student_ID      DrivingLicenseNumber
0  Smith  2222       1234               DL1234
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try mapping each unique key to the others. For example, a double loop like this:

```
# map the string `None` to nan if necessary
df = df.mask(df=='None', np.nan)

keys = ['SSN', 'Student_ID','DrivingLicenseNumber']
for k in keys:
    maps = df.dropna(subset=[k]).groupby(k).first()
    for c in keys:
        if c == k: continue
        df[c] = df[c].fillna(df[k].map(maps[c]))
```

After that, the data frame will look like this:

```
    Name   SSN Student_ID DrivingLicenseNumber
0  Smith  2222       1234               DL1234
1  Smith  2222       1234               DL1234
2  Smith  2222       1234               DL1234
3    NaN  2222       1234               DL1234
```

From which, we can use any unique key to drop duplicates:

```
df.groupby('SSN').first()
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying the above - but getting KeyError: ['Name'], I printed the df to make sure the column 'Name' is the first one (though there are many NaN's in that column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby.first` with `mask`:

```
df.mask(df.eq('None')|df.eq(None)).groupby('Name').first()
```

Here not sure `'None'` is a string or `None`. If you are sure you can use of the condition instead of both in mask.

---

You can also try:

```
df = df.mask(df.eq('None')|df.eq(None))
df = df.fillna(df.groupby('SSN').transform('ffill'))
df = df.fillna(df.groupby('Name').transform('ffill'))
df = df.fillna(df.groupby('Student_ID').transform('ffill'))
df = df.groupby('Name').first()
```

Comment: It's interesting that you don't `groupby` on unique keys.

Comment: @QuangHoang I fixed it.